# rails api only, как получить параметры из заголовков?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

Здравствуйте!

Эксперементирую с API приложением. Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
сейчас я могу принять запрос с параметрами только в виде:

`http://localhost:3000/user?firstname=Иван&lastname=Иванов`

Соответственно, в контроллере я обрабатываю их как `params[:firstname]` и `params[:lastname]`

А вот как мне принимать параметры, переданные в заголовках?

```
POST /user HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: insomnia/5.10.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
firstname: Иван
lastname: Иванов
Content-Length: 41
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого следует воспользоваться хэшом request.headers, который будет вам доступен на уровне контроллера в экшенах, например,

```
Rails.logger.info request.headers['firstname']
Rails.logger.info request.headers['lastname']
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! А может еще подскажите, как получить параметры из json?

Comment: @PumPurum Если json в строке, его можно преобразовать при помощи JSON.load(json_string) - результатом будет обычный Ruby-хэш. require 'json'  JSON.load('{"hello":"world"}')['hello']. Вы можете задавать новый вопрос - их количество не ограничено.